# Navbar Item Order with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a different problem. My Navbar order is gone backward. So I changed code order to 3-2-1 instead of 1-2-3 for showing 1-2-3. This is my code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                        aria-expanded="false">Hesap <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ayarlar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>
                                <a>Bilgisayara Son Erişim : 22:22:39 - 10.07.2015</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Çıkış Yap : scrappy@kodevreni.com</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right">Kayıtlar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right">Ekran Görüntüsü</a>
                <a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right">Yönetim</a>
            </div>
```

I want to make it like this "Yönetim > Ekran Görüntüsü > Kayıtlar > Hesap (dropdown)". But It makes it backward so I changed the code upside down. But the problem is it shows as normal in mobile drop down button...

Comment: Please create a `JSFiddle` or show us your piece of code for clarification of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `a` tag `float` `right` as like this .

```css
a.btn.btn-link.navbar-btn.navbar-right{float:right;}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right">Kayıtlar</a>
                <a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right">Ekran Görüntüsü</a>
                <a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right">Yönetim</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello please check this method it will work

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
                    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Yönetim</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ekran Görüntüsü</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kayıtlar</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

            <li class="dropdown-header"></li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Ayarlar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kayıtlar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bilgisayara Son Erişim : 22:22:39 - 10.07.2015</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Çıkış Yap : scrappy@kodevreni.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```